# How to set DisplayDateTimeStart on WPF (MahApps.Metro) datetime picker

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker, mahapps.metro

In my UI I am able to set Minimum date for date picker using following code :

```
<Controls:DateTimePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}"
                         DisplayDateStart="{Binding LastUpdatedValue}" 
                         Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="89,1,0,10" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
```

This takes out all the previous dates for selection which is fine. Is there way to restrict time as well.

For example, If I have selected 15 June 2018, 3:34:06 PM as my start date , the time picker should restrict any time that's before it.

If I select the date as 16 , then all time range can be available to select.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK there is no native date-time picker in WPF, only a `DatePicker`. Which component do you use?

Comment: @dymanoid, My bad . I am using mahapps.metro,tagged it now.

Comment: if the control does not support this, maybe you can handle it in the code behind by reset the selected time after user selection - kind of awkward...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there way to restrict time as well.

You can set the `SourceHours`, `SourceMinutes` and `SourceSeconds` properties of the `DateTimePicker` control to a range of integers (`IEnumerable<int>`) that you want to be displayed in the `ComboBoxes`.

But I am afraid there is no "DisplayTimeStart" property that does this for you automatically.

Comment: And will  this restrict the hours,minutes, seconds  for future dates as well?

Comment: @Simsons: You restrict the selection of *dates* using the `DisplayDateEnd` property.